# App Crashing with android material Chip Group with material 1.3.0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-chips

I have an issue with this

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.truesight/com.truesight.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.truesight:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #27 in com.truesight:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.truesight:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #27 in com.truesight:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27 in com.truesight:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

this is my xml code, I am trying to use chip group with a horizontal scroll view in relative layout and scroll view

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/grad_bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:singleLine="true"
            app:singleSelection="true">

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Valorant"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="CS:GO"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="DotA 2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="PUBG"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
                android:layout_width="160dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/et_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:text="Mobile Legends"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />


        </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>


    </HorizontalScrollView>


<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    app:itemBackground="@color/nav_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

i was set my Parents Theme with

```
<style name="AppTheme." parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

and used dependencies with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

Comment: Why do you put **a dot** after your Theme's name: `AppTheme.`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your AppTheme with this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
```

Comment: Bridge is better~ "Bridge themes inherit from AppCompat themes, but also define the new Material Components theme attributes for you. If you use a bridge theme, you can start using Material Design components without changing your app theme."

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `theme` individually to all your `chips` which will be overriding the application or parent theme

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    <!-- other props -->
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light />
```